# Connect to ubuntu port from docker container

Tags: ubuntu, networking, docker, wget

I have a application running on port 8180 on my local machine
When I try to `wget http://192.168.1.12:8180/auth` from docker container,
I get following error

```
--2019-10-10 08:17:03--  http://192.168.1.12:8180/auth
Connecting to 192.168.1.12:8180... failed: Connection refused.
```

I tried following

```
❯ sudo ufw status                                                                                                                                        [14:17:44]
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8180/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8180/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Still getting the same error.

I have also tried `--add-host="www.kkk.com:192.168.1.12"`

and tried `http://www.kkk.com:8180/auth`

still got same issue

How to fix this??

```
❯ netstat -tnl |grep 8180                                                                                                                                [16:39:04]
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8180          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Comment: `Connection refused` suggests that nothing is listening on that port on the target server.

Comment: i know what i means. there is a server running. still getting this error

Comment: Just that it's running doesn't mean that it's listening on that interface. Your post does not contain enough information to analyze the issue.

Comment: from the host machine when i go http://localhost:8180/auth i get response

Comment: Please run `netstat -tnl |grep 8180` and edit the output into your question.

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service is only listening on the loopback interface (`127.0.0.1`). To make it available on other interfaces bind it to `192.168.1.12` or `0.0.0.0` instead (to have it listen on all interfaces).